# Editing the particular element of list in react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function, react-native, binding

I am creating a list of items on react having express running on backend with edit and delete button. I am working on the edit button for now and want to display the id of the particular element on the console after the button is pressed but instead of Displaying Id it is showing blank.

```
I have tried putting other element but none works
```

/category.tsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom'
import { ReactComponent } from '*.svg';
import {showitems} from './userfunctions'
const mystyles = {
    color:'white',
    display:'inline-block'
  } as React.CSSProperties;

interface catprops{}
```

/mainclass

```
export class category extends Component<catprops,any> {
    constructor(props:catprops){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            tableData: [],
            sno:0,
            id:''
        }
        this.handleclick= this.handleclick.bind(this); //for binding the button with particular id
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        showitems().then(res=>{
            if(res==null)
            {
                console.log("not found");
            }
            else
            this.setState({tableData:res});
        })

    }
```

//main handle function handling the onclick event

```
    handleclick =(e:any) =>{
        this.setState({[this.state.id]: e.target.value});
        console.log(this.state.id);
    }
```

/render function

```
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <table className="table">
                    <thead className="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                    <th>S.no</th>
                    <th>Category Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Created On</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
```

//data rendering table

```
                    </tr> </thead>
                    {
                        this.state.tableData.map((res:any,index:any) =>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{index+1}</td>
                        <td>{res.cname}</td>
                        <td>{res.description}</td>
                        <td>{res.created_on}</td>
                        <td><button value={res._id} onClick={this.handleclick}>Edit</button> //this button 
<button>Delete</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    )
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default category
```

//expectations

```
I am expecting the Id on the console but it is showing blank on console because I have initialized it as blank.
```

I am expecting the Id on the console but it is showing blank on console because I have initialized it as blank.

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```js
    handleclick = (e:any) =>{
        this.setState({id: e.target.value}, () => {
           console.log(this.state.id);
        });
    }
```